# QSet<func pointer> does not compile by gcc

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, function-pointers, qhash

I'm trying to use `QSet` for storing a list of function pointers. See this code for more details. The problem is that this code does not compile by gcc/mingw. MSVC compiles it normally. What am I doing wrong?

```
typedef intptr_t (*UikHook)(intptr_t);
...
typedef struct
{
    QSet<UikHook>*  qsetSubscribers;
    //QMutex*           qmutexHook;
} THookableEvent;
...
THookableEvent* p = qmapHooks_.value(name);
if (p->qsetSubscribers == 0)
    p->qsetSubscribers = new QSet<UikHook>();
p->qsetSubscribers->insert(hookProc);

error: no matching function for call to ‘qHash(long int (* const&)(long int))’
```

Perhaps, I should to declare `operator==` and function `qHash()` for type `UikHook` as it said in the docs, but I dont know how to do it  because when I'm declaring `opertator==`, I get the following error:

```
inline bool operator==(const UikHook &e1, const UikHook &e2)

error: ‘bool operator==(intptr_t (* const&)(intptr_t), intptr_t (* const&)(intptr_t))’ 
must have an argument of class or enumerated type
```

P.S. I'm using Qt 5.8, gcc 6.2, msvc2015

Update: Solved by replacing QSet to QVector.

Comment: BTW, `typedef struct {` is C, not C++. In C++ it's just `struct THookableEvent {`. This is important because you otherwise can't define a ctor.

Answer (score 2):

You can't define an `operator==` for built-in types, such as pointers, integers or floating-point numbers. They already have it. You just need to provide a `qHash`.

Comment: Same question as comment above. How to write correct qHash function? My try does not work.
`inline uint qHash(const UikHook& key, uint seed = 0)
{
 return reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(key);
}`

Comment: @Sergey: Why not? Have you googled the error you get?

Comment: Same error: no matching function for call to ‘qHash(long int (* const&)(long int))’

Answer (score 1):

Using function pointers is not really the best practice in C++. In early C++ versions, functors were used instead. Since C++11, there are real function objects. You can convert a function pointer to an object via `std::function()` ([Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)).

If the compilers you listed are the ones you need to support, I strongly suggest using `std::function` instead of function pointers.

Comment: Okay, but how to write a correct qHash function for  std::function<intptr_t(intptr_t)>?

Comment: Well, maybe the set is not the right container for you to use? How do you access these functions after storing them? Just iterating through? Then you should use `QVector` or `QList`.

Answer (score 0):

Try (warning, brain compile):

```
template <typename R, typename ...A>
inline uint qHash(R (*)(A...) const f) noexcept
{
  return std::hash<R (*)(A...)>()(f);
}
```

Qt is in a fix here, since it can't use the STL and hashing function pointers is somewhat compiler specific.